# How would you write this htaccess rewriterule?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm essentially making a proxy -- you put the URL at the end of a path and my servers download it and display it.

How can I rewrite `http://www.example.com/search/dl/http://www.example.com/image.png`

To `http://www.example.com/search/download.php?url=http://www.example.com/image.png`

I've been unable to find any solutions to this - I think the /s may be causing me problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the htaccess file in your document root, you need:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /search/dl/(http://[^\ \?]+)
RewriteRule ^search/dl/ /search/download.php?url=%1 [L]
```

You need to match against the `%{THE_REQUEST}` variable because the two slashes behind the `http:` gets removed when the request URI is canonicalized, so you can match against it in the rewrite rule's regex pattern.

---

If you put these rules in the `/search/` directory, they won't work at all. You need to remove the "search" from the pattern that tries to match it, since the "search" will be missing from the URI so you can't match against it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /search/dl/(http://[^\ \?]+)
RewriteRule ^dl/ /search/download.php?url=%1 [L]
```

Comment: Giving me an Internal Server Error [500] when trying to redirect for some reason.

Comment: @BetaBlaze Sorry, I left out the pattern in the rule

Comment: The 500 error went away, but now it's giving a 404 error stating that "/search/dl/..." does not exist. The download.php script is already made, just waiting to be linked to. Any other ideas? >_<

Comment: @BetaBlaze Dunno, [it works perfectly fine for me in my blank htaccess file and vanilla test apache setup](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Qhu7S.png)

Comment: Since you did help, please add this as an "OR" option to your answer, and I'll accept it. (The below is what worked for me.)

RewriteRule ^dl/(.*) download.php?url=$1 [L,NC]

Comment: @BetaBlaze You put the rules in the htaccess file in your `/search/` directory? I stated that the rules needed to go into the document root, but if you want it in the search directory, then you need to get rid of that from the path.

Comment: I did put it in root; I just decided to make a new rule based on some code I found in an old site, and put it in the local dir, since the code you provided wasn't working for me... for some strange reason.